# kill multiple processes on multiple remote machines

Tags: powershell, process, kill

[Kill a process on multiple remote machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161211/kill-a-process-on-multiple-remote-machines/38865518#38865518)

kill multiple processes on multiple remote machines

get-content .\killprocess.PS1

(Get-Content 'U:\Accounts\Computers.txt') | ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -computer $_ -class win32_process  -filter "name = 'synergy.exe'" -credential $cred| %{$_.terminate()} | out-null}

How do I add a second process to terminate into the mix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Running this locally but you can use `OR` to add more conditionals to your query.

For example:

`Get-WmiObject -class win32_process -filter "name='chrome.exe' or name='conhost.exe'"`

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: Great thanks, just about the only thing I didn't try lol OR, cheers

Comment: @LeighCarmichael can you mark this as the accepted answer?  Thanks